# My object and grid disappeared

Tags: 3d-view

This may be a stupid question, but I think I accidentally pressed something so now both my object and the grid has disappeared. Can someone please help me because I've been looking at it for hours and it's driving me insane!!! [image]

Comment: If josh sanfelici's answer doesn't work, you're also in Local view as you can see from the top-left of the viewport so press the '/' key with the cursor over the 3D window to exit that view.

Comment: Yeah, I tried josh and your method, but it still gives me a blank canvas... ;(

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file in that case. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there. Don't forget to add a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

Go the outliner (Top right window), select the cube, hover over the 3D main window and press the "dot" key on numpad (or go to menu > View > Frame selected).

Works also with "Home" Key, which is the shortcut for menu > View > Frame all.